# SAS - Model Validation - Kevin Kennedy

Tags: sas, statistics, modeling

So I'm having trouble getting what appears to be a fairly common model validation macro to run with my code. Here's the code:

```
%macro hoslem (data=, pred=, y=, ngro=10,print=T,out=hl);
/*---
Macro computes the Hosmer-Lemeshow Chi Square Statistic
for Calibration
Parameters (* = required)
-------------------------
data* input dataset
pred* Predicted Probabilities
y* Outcome 0/1 variable
ngro # of groups for the calibration test (default 10)
print Prints output (set to F to Suppress)
out output dataset (default HL)
Author: Kevin Kennedy
---*/
%let print = %upcase(&print);
proc format;
value pval 0-.0001='<.0001';
run;
data first;set &data;where &y^=. and &pred^=.;run;
proc rank groups=&ngro out=ranks data=first;ranks phat_grp;var &pred;run;
proc sort data=ranks;by phat_grp;run;
proc sql;
create table ranks2 as select *, count(*) as num_dec label='Sample Size', sum(&pred) as sum_pred
label='Sum Probabilities', sum(&y) as sum_y label='Number of Events'
from ranks
group by phat_grp;
create table ranks3 as select distinct(phat_grp),num_dec,sum_pred,sum_y,
((sum_y-sum_pred)**2/(sum_pred*(1-sum_pred/num_dec))) as chi_part label 'Chi-Square Term'
from ranks2 ;
select sum(chi_part) into :chi_sq
from ranks3;
quit;
data &out;
chi_sq=&chi_sq; label chi_sq='Hosmer Lemeshow Chi Square';
df=&ngro-2; label df ='Degree of Freedom';
p_value=1-cdf('chisquared',chi_sq,df);label p_value= 'P-Value';
format p_value pval.;
run;
%if &print=T %then %do;
 title 'Hosmer Lemeshow Details';
 proc print data=ranks3 noobs label;run;
 Options formdlim='-';
 title 'Hosmer Lemeshow Calibration Test';
 proc print data=&out noobs label;run;
%end;
Options formdlim='';
%mend; 
%macro add_predictive(data=, y=, p_old=, p_new= , nripoints=%str(),hoslemgrp=10) ;
/*---
this macro attempts to quantify the added predictive ability of a covariate(s)
in logistic regression based off of the statistics in: M. J. Pencina ET AL. Statistics
in Medicine (2008 27(2):157-72). Statistics returned with be: C-statistics (for 9.2 users),
IDI (INTEGRATED DISCRIMINATION IMPROVEMENT), NRI (net reclassification index)
for both Category-Free and User defined groups, and Hosmer Lemeshow GOF test
with associated pvalues and z scores.
Parameters (* = required)
-------------------------
data* Specifies the SAS dataset
y* Response variable (Outcome must be 0/1)
p_old* Predicted Probability of an Event using Initial Model
p_new* Predicted Probability of an Event using New Model
nripoints Groups for User defined classification (Optional),
 Example 3 groups: (<.06, .06-.2, >.2) then nripoints=.06 .2
hoslemgrp # of groups for the Hosmer Lemeshow test (default 10)
Author: Kevin Kennedy and Michael Pencina
Date: May 26, 2010
---*/
options nonotes nodate nonumber;
ods select none;
%local start end ;
%let start=%sysfunc(datetime());
proc format;
value pval 0-.0001='<.0001';
run;
/******Step 1: C-Statistics******/
/********************************/
%if %sysevalf(&sysver >= 9.2) %then %do;
%put ********Running AUC Analysis************;
 proc logistic data=&data descending;
 model &y=&p_old &p_new;
 roc 'first' &p_old;
 roc 'second' &p_new;
 roccontrast reference('first')/estimate e;
 ods output ROCAssociation=rocass ROCContrastEstimate=rocdiff;
 run;
 proc sql noprint;
 select estimate, StdErr, lowercl, uppercl, (ProbChiSq*100) as pval
 into :rocdiff, :rocdiff_stderr, :rocdiff_low, :rocdiff_up, :rocp
 from rocdiff
 where find(contrast,'second');
 quit;
 data _null_;
 set rocass;
 if ROCModel='first' then do;
 call symputx('c_old',Area);
 end;
 if ROCModel='second' then do;
 call symputx('c_new',Area);
 end;
 run;
 data cstat;
 cstat_old=&c_old; label cstat_old='Model1 AUC';
 cstat_new=&c_new; label cstat_new='Model2 AUC';
 cstat_diff=&rocdiff; label cstat_diff='Difference in AUC';
 cstat_stderr=&rocdiff_stderr; label cstat_stderr='Standard Error of Difference in AUC';
 cstat_low=&rocdiff_low; label cstat_low='Difference in AUC Lower 95% CI'; 
 cstat_up=&rocdiff_up; label cstat_up='Difference in ACU Upper 95% CI';
 cstat_ci='('!!trim(left(cstat_low))!!','!!trim(left(cstat_up))!!')';
 label cstat_ci='95% CI for Difference in AUC';
 cstat_pval=&rocp/100; label cstat_pval='P-value for AUC Difference';
 format cstat_pval pval.;
 run;
%end;
%if %sysevalf(&sysver < 9.2) %then %do;
options notes ;
%put *********************;
%put NOTE: You are running a Pre 9.2 version of SAS;
%put NOTE: Go to SAS website to get example of ROC Macro for AUC Comps;
%put NOTE: http://support.sas.com/kb/25/017.html;
%put *********************;
%put;
options nonotes ;
%end;
/******************************/
/*****End step 1***************/
/******************************/
/******Step 2: IDI***************/
%put ********Running IDI Analysis************;
proc sql noprint;
create table idinri as select &y,&p_old, &p_new, (&p_new-&p_old) as pdiff
from &data
where &p_old^=. and &p_new^=.
order by &y;
quit;
proc sql noprint; /*define mean probabilities for old and new model and event and nonevent*/
select count(*),avg(&p_old), avg(&p_new),stderr(pdiff) into
:num_event, :p_event_old, :p_event_new,:eventstderr
from idinri
where &y=1 ;
select count(*),avg(&p_old), avg(&p_new),stderr(pdiff) into
:num_nonevent, :p_nonevent_old, :p_nonevent_new ,:noneventstderr
from idinri
where &y=0;
quit;
data fin(drop=slope_noadd slope_add);
pen=&p_event_new; label pen='Mean Probability for Events: Model2';
peo=&p_event_old; label peo='Mean Probability for Events: Model1';
pnen=&p_nonevent_new; label pnen='Mean Probability for NonEvents: Model2';
pneo=&p_nonevent_old; label pneo='Mean Probability for NonEvents: Model1';
idi=(&p_event_new-&p_nonevent_new)-(&p_event_old-&p_nonevent_old);
label idi='Integrated Discrimination Improvement';
idi_stderr=sqrt((&eventstderr**2)+(&noneventstderr**2));
label idi_stderr='IDI Standard Error';
idi_lowci=round(idi-1.96*idi_stderr,.0001);
idi_upci=round(idi+1.96*idi_stderr,.0001);
idi_ci='('!!trim(left(idi_lowci))!!','!!trim(left(idi_upci))!!')';
label idi_ci='IDI 95% CI';
z_idi=abs(idi/(sqrt((&eventstderr**2)+(&noneventstderr**2))));
label z_idi='Z-value for IDI';
pvalue_idi=2*(1-PROBNORM(abs(z_idi))); label pvalue_idi='P-value for IDI';
change_event=&p_event_new-&p_event_old;
label change_event='Probability change for Events';
change_nonevent=&p_nonevent_new-&p_nonevent_old;
label change_nonevent='Probability change for Nonevents';
slope_noadd=&p_event_old-&p_nonevent_old;
slope_add=&p_event_new-&p_nonevent_new;
relative_idi=slope_add/slope_noadd-1; label relative_idi='Relative IDI';
format pvalue_idi pval.;
run;
/************step 3 NRI analysis*******/
%put ********Running NRI Analysis************;
data nri_inf;
set idinri;
if &y=1 then do;
 down_event=(pdiff<0);up_event=(pdiff>0);down_nonevent=0;up_nonevent=0;
end;
if &y=0 then do;
 down_nonevent=(pdiff<0);up_nonevent=(pdiff>0);down_event=0;up_event=0;
end; 
run;
proc sql;
select sum(up_nonevent), sum(down_nonevent), sum(up_event),sum(down_event)
into :num_nonevent_up_user, :num_nonevent_down_user, :num_event_up_user, :num_event_down_user
from nri_inf
quit;
/* Category-Free Groups */
data nri1;
group="Category-Free NRI";
p_up_event=&num_event_up_user/&num_event;
p_down_event=&num_event_down_user/&num_event;
p_up_nonevent=&num_nonevent_up_user/&num_nonevent;
p_down_nonevent=&num_nonevent_down_user/&num_nonevent;
nri=(p_up_event-p_down_event)-(p_up_nonevent-p_down_nonevent);
nri_stderr=sqrt(((&num_event_up_user+&num_event_down_user)/&num_event**2-(&num_event_up_user-
&num_event_down_user)**2/&num_event**3)+
 ((&num_nonevent_down_user+&num_nonevent_up_user)/&num_nonevent**2-
(&num_nonevent_down_user-&num_nonevent_up_user)**2/&num_nonevent**3));
low_nrici=round(nri-1.96*nri_stderr,.0001);
up_nrici=round(nri+1.96*nri_stderr,.0001);
nri_ci='('!!trim(left(low_nrici))!!','!!trim(left(up_nrici))!!')';
z_nri=nri/sqrt(((p_up_event+p_down_event)/&num_event)
+((p_up_nonevent+p_down_nonevent)/&num_nonevent)) ;
pvalue_nri=2*(1-PROBNORM(abs(z_nri)));
event_correct_reclass=p_up_event-p_down_event;
nonevent_correct_reclass=p_down_nonevent-p_up_nonevent;
z_event=event_correct_reclass/sqrt((p_up_event+p_down_event)/&num_event);
pvalue_event=2*(1-probnorm(abs(z_event)));
z_nonevent=nonevent_correct_reclass/sqrt((p_up_nonevent+p_down_nonevent)/&num_nonevent);
pvalue_nonevent=2*(1-probnorm(abs(z_nonevent)));
format pvalue_nri pvalue_event pvalue_nonevent pval. event_correct_reclass
nonevent_correct_reclass percent.;
label nri='Net Reclassification Improvement'
 nri_stderr='NRI Standard Error'
 low_nrici='NRI lower 95% CI'
 up_nrici='NRI upper 95% CI'
 nri_ci='NRI 95% CI'
 z_nri='Z-Value for NRI'
 pvalue_nri='NRI P-Value'
 pvalue_event='Event P-Value'
 pvalue_nonevent='Non-Event P-Value'
 event_correct_reclass='% of Events correctly reclassified'
 nonevent_correct_reclass='% of Nonevents correctly reclassified';
run;
/*User Defined NRI*/
%if &nripoints^=%str() %then %do;
 /*words macro*/
 %macro words(list,delim=%str( ));
 %local count;
 %let count=0;
 %do %while(%qscan(%bquote(&list),&count+1,%str(&delim)) ne %str());
 %let count=%eval(&count+1);
 %end;
 &count
 %mend words;
%let numgroups=%eval(%words(&nripoints)+1); /*figure out how many ordinal groups*/
 proc format ;
 value group
 1 = "0 to %scan(&nripoints,1,%str( ))"
 %do i=2 %to %eval(&numgroups-1);
 %let j=%eval(&i-1);
 &i="%scan(&nripoints,&j,%str( )) to %scan(&nripoints,&i,%str( ))"
 %end;
%let j=%eval(&numgroups-1);
 &numgroups="%scan(&nripoints,&j,%str( )) to 1";
 run;
data idinri;
set idinri;
/*define first ordinal group for pre and post*/
if 0<=&p_old<=%scan(&nripoints,1,%str( )) then group_pre=1;
if 0<=&p_new<=%scan(&nripoints,1,%str( )) then group_post=1;
%let i=1;
%do %until(&i>%eval(&numgroups-1)); 
 if %scan(&nripoints,&i,%str( ))<&p_old then do;
 group_pre=&i+1;
 end;
 if %scan(&nripoints,&i,%str( ))<&p_new then do;
 group_post=&i+1;
 end;
 %let i=%eval(&i+1);
%end;
if &y=0 then do;
 up_nonevent=(group_post>group_pre);
 down_nonevent=(group_post<group_pre);
 down_event=0; up_event=0;
end;
if &y=1 then do;
 up_event=(group_post>group_pre);
 down_event=(group_post<group_pre);
 down_nonevent=0; up_nonevent=0;
end;
format group_pre group_post group.;
run;
proc sql;
select sum(up_nonevent), sum(down_nonevent), sum(up_event),sum(down_event),avg(&y)
 into :num_nonevent_up_user, :num_nonevent_down_user, :num_event_up_user,
:num_event_down_user, :eventrate
from idinri
 quit;
data nri2;
 group='User Category NRI';
 p_up_event=&num_event_up_user/&num_event;
 p_down_event=&num_event_down_user/&num_event;
 p_up_nonevent=&num_nonevent_up_user/&num_nonevent;
 p_down_nonevent=&num_nonevent_down_user/&num_nonevent;
 nri=(p_up_event-p_down_event)-(p_up_nonevent-p_down_nonevent);
 nri_stderr=sqrt(((&num_event_up_user+&num_event_down_user)/&num_event**2-
(&num_event_up_user-&num_event_down_user)**2/&num_event**3)+
 ((&num_nonevent_down_user+&num_nonevent_up_user)/&num_nonevent**2-
(&num_nonevent_down_user-&num_nonevent_up_user)**2/&num_nonevent**3));
 low_nrici=round(nri-1.96*nri_stderr,.0001);
 up_nrici=round(nri+1.96*nri_stderr,.0001);
 nri_ci='('!!trim(left(low_nrici))!!','!!trim(left(up_nrici))!!')';
 z_nri=nri/sqrt(((p_up_event+p_down_event)/&num_event)
+((p_up_nonevent+p_down_nonevent)/&num_nonevent)) ;
 pvalue_nri=2*(1-PROBNORM(abs(z_nri)));
 event_correct_reclass=p_up_event-p_down_event;
 nonevent_correct_reclass=p_down_nonevent-p_up_nonevent;
 z_event=event_correct_reclass/sqrt((p_up_event+p_down_event)/&num_event);
 pvalue_event=2*(1-probnorm(abs(z_event)));
 z_nonevent=nonevent_correct_reclass/sqrt((p_up_nonevent+p_down_nonevent)/&num_nonevent);
 pvalue_nonevent=2*(1-probnorm(abs(z_nonevent)));
format pvalue_nri pval.;
run;
data nri1;
set nri1 nri2;
run;
%end;
/**************/
/*step 4 gof */
/**************/
%hoslem(data=idinri,pred=&p_old,y=&y,ngro=&hoslemgrp,out=m1,print=F);
%hoslem(data=idinri,pred=&p_new,y=&y,ngro=&hoslemgrp,out=m2,print=F);
data hoslem(drop=cnt);
retain model;
set m1 m2;
cnt+1;
if cnt=1 then model='Model1';
else model='Model2';
run;
ods select all;
/*output for cstat*/
%if %sysevalf(&sysver >= 9.2) %then %do;
proc print data=cstat label noobs;
title1 "Evaluating added predictive ability of model2";
title2 'AUC Analysis';run; 
%END;
/*output for IDI*/
proc print data=fin label noobs;
title1 "Evaluating added predictive ability of model2";
title2 'IDI Analysis';
var idi idi_stderr z_idi pvalue_idi idi_ci
pen peo pnen pneo change_event change_nonevent relative_idi;
run;
/*output for NRI*/
proc print data=nri1 label noobs;
title1 "Evaluating added predictive ability of model2";
title2 'NRI Analysis';
var group nri nri_stderr z_nri pvalue_nri nri_ci event_correct_reclass pvalue_event
nonevent_correct_reclass pvalue_nonevent;
run;
%if &nripoints^=%str() %then %do;
proc freq data=idinri;
where &y=0;
title 'NRI Table for Non-Events';
tables group_pre*group_post/nopercent nocol;
run;
proc freq data=idinri;
where &y=1;
title 'NRI Table for Events';
tables group_pre*group_post/nopercent nocol;
run;
%end;
/*print HL gof*/
proc print data=hoslem noobs label;
title "Hosmer Lemeshow Test with %sysevalf(&hoslemgrp-2) df";
run;
proc datasets library=work nolist;
delete fin idinri nri1 nri2 nri_inf stderr;
quit;
options notes;
%put NOTE: Macro %nrstr(%%)add_predictive completed.;
%let end=%sysfunc(datetime());
%let runtime=%sysfunc(round(%sysevalf(&end-&start)));
%put NOTE: Macro Real Run Time=&runtime seconds;
title;
%mend; 


/*initial model*/
proc logistic data=DATA;
model value(event='1')=X1-X20;
output out=m1 pred=p1;
run;

/*new model*/
proc logistic data=data;
model value(event='1')=X1-X20;
output out=m2 pred=p2;
run;

proc sql;
create table TABLENAME as select *
from m1 as a left join m2 as b on a.cnt=b.cnt;
quit;

%add_predictive(data=DATA,y=value,p_old=p1,p_new=p2, nripoints=.1 .3);
```

The error I get after running is:

ERROR: Column cnt could not be found in the table/view identified with the correlation name A.
ERROR: Column cnt could not be found in the table/view identified with the correlation name A.
ERROR: Column cnt could not be found in the table/view identified with the correlation name B.
ERROR: Column cnt could not be found in the table/view identified with the correlation name B.

However when trouble shooting it seems to take me down a never ending path of unrecognized variables. Am I calling the macro incorrectly?

Comment: You're running `PROC LOGISTIC` on a dataset called `DATA`. Nowhere in the code can I find this dataset having been created or otherwise referenced, does the dataset - `DATA` have a column called `cnt`? Also, consider naming your datasets more imaginatively.

Comment: DATA is just referencing the infile. Although, your statement regarding cnt was important. So I added this statement:

data DATA;
    set model _1;
    readmit=(event='1'); 
    cnt+1;
    run;

So now the infile is model_1 and DATA is the dataset

Comment: Have you tried looking at the output from `OPTIONS MLOGIC MPRINT SYMBOLGEN;`?